# How to clear all history in linux/ubuntu terminal or bash permanently?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

When you use the up key in a Linux terminal, you can use previous commands again. Great feature. However, I started logging mysql into mysql with the sensitive details in the command.

How can I delete that history permanently?

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to mention that I'm using bash.

Comment: Since this question is closed I can't add this as an answer. You can tell bash not to save any history for a particular session with this command: `export HISTFILE=/dev/null`

Comment: I can also add this: do not enter sensitive info to command line - wait for prompt :D

Answer (score 346, accepted):

You can clear your bash history like this:

`history -cw`

Comment: Really like this answer - this takes effect immediately, rather than deleting `.bash_history` which requires the shell to be restarted to take effect.

Comment: Does not work on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. History just appears with new terminal. All that worked is `>~/bash_history`. Have to restart terminal for this though.

Comment: Also works on Mac OS X El Capitan (tested on version 10.11.2), but you have to add that following line to your `~/.bash_profile`: `export SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0`, then do a `source ~/.bash_profile` and to finish quit and restart your Terminal app. If you want to understand what this export command does, then you should definitely check this following link: http://superuser.com/questions/950403/bash-history-not-preserved-between-terminal-sessions-on-mac

Comment: isn't only -c enough? Manuals says -c clears the history list by deleting all of the entries. -w wirtes the current history to history file and append them to history list. Just -c works fine.

Answer (score 26):

If you use bash, then the terminal history is saved in a file called .bash_history. Delete it, and history will be gone.

However, for MySQL the better approach is not to enter the password in the command line. If you just specify the -p option, without a value, then you will be prompted for the password and it won't be logged.

Another option, if you don't want to enter your password every time, is to store it in a my.cnf file. Create a file named ~/.my.cnf with something like:

```
[client]
user = <username>
password = <password>
```

Make sure to change the file permissions so that only you can read the file.

Of course, this way your password is still saved in a plaintext file in your home directory, just like it was previously saved in .bash_history.

Comment: +1 for specifying `-p`. This is totally the correct approach for this problem

Comment: Actually, on my Linux system, bash remembers the history and recreates the file on logout.  You'd have to log in, delete the file, log in again, log out the first shell, delete the file, and then log out the second shell.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I thought I was being smart by using the -p+password option directly in the command because it was so much faster to just press the up arrow as I have a very long password. Time to reconsider..

Comment: Don't forget to `unset HISTFILE` so that the current history isn't saved.

Comment: I edited my answer and added a solution that prevents from entering the password every time.

Comment: The better approach if you are using mysql 5.6 is the use of mysql_config_editor that uses an encrypted configuration file .mylogin.cnf instead the plain text .my.cnf [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html)