# Clear history in Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, terminal

I would like to clear my history in the Mongo shell (OSX/Terminal). I have tried the command 'cls' and it clears the text in the terminal. However, when I run my next query all of which I cleared reappears along with the new information from the query. How can I prevent the history from reappearing?

This question is not a possible duplicate because the answer was to use CMD+K in the mongo shell as mentioned by the accepted answer below. The suggested duplicate was unrelated.

Comment: Just use in in *incognito* mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete terminal history in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709349/delete-terminal-history-in-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for [How to really clear the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/25079).
`reset` command will do the job.

Or you can try <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> button to clear scrollback buffer in OS X as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327218/how-to-clear-console-in-mongodb).

Comment: I quit the mongo shell and ran the command 'reset' and it cleared the text in the terminal. When I entered the mongo shell again and ran a query on a collection e.g. findOne, I was presented with the single object along with the entire history, so it did not work. I also tried the 'tput reset' command and still no luck. Any other suggesstions? I'd presume the command should be something ran inside the mongo shell and not outside.

Comment: You can try `command+k` button that is used to clear scrollback buffer. If that still does not work, then try punching enter key several times will send new lines on your display, then run a mongo query. See if it works

Comment: Pressing 'Command + K' in the mongo shell resolved the issue. Thank you for your help.